# Error getting value from ... with JSon exception and nullException

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio, entity-framework

this is a pretty tough problem I got here, I don't get anything to it, I'll try to be as clear as possible

I'm working on a project which takes datas in a database and create Json files from it, here's the method that throws the Exception :

```
public async Task<int> RecupInters(List<string> fileExist)
    {
            List<JsonFile> ljf = (await myservice.getJsonFilesAsync(Switcher.pageSwitcher.currentUser, fileExist.ToArray())).ToList();
        if (ljf.Count > 0)
            {
                float percentPerFile = 50 / ljf.Count;
                string jsonFolder = Data.HelperDirectory.getFolderDocumentAndCreate("JSON");
                float percent = 0.0f;
                foreach (JsonFile jf in ljf)
                {
                    this.changeValues("Récupération de nouveaux rapports", percent, "Sauvegarde des fichiers d'interventions");
                    File.WriteAllText(jsonFolder + jf.Name, jf.Content);
                    percent = percent + percentPerFile;
                }
            }
            return ljf.Count;
    }
```

It says "Error getting value from demandeAideFilledAndItsMine" and throws a JsonSerialization exception and a nullReferenceException. demandeAidefilledAndItsMine is a property of the FichePreDiag class :

```
public bool demandeAideFilledAndItsMine { get { return (this.NomDemandeAide != null && isMine()); } }
```

(here is the IsMine method if you want)

```
public bool isMine()
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(this.NomDemandeAide))
        {
            return this.NomDemandeAide.Equals(DAL.getUserByUsername(Environment.UserName).fullName);
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
```

And the FichePreDiag class is a DB Object generated by EntityFramework. 
Anyway, actually the Exception is thrown when it calls the method getJsonFilesAsync so I digged deep into it, it comes from here :

```
public System.Threading.Tasks.Task<DAO.JsonFile[]> getJsonFilesAsync(DAO.User u, string[] fileExist) {
        return base.Channel.getJsonFilesAsync(u, fileExist);
    }
```

This method belongs to a partial class and calls the method of the same name in a reference :

```
[System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/IService1/getJsonFiles", ReplyAction="http://tempuri.org/IService1/getJsonFilesResponse")]
    System.Threading.Tasks.Task<DAO.JsonFile[]> getJsonFilesAsync(DAO.User u, string[] fileExist);
```

And I can't get deeper. I'm soooo confused right now, I need help.

Thanks for your time

Comment: "and throws a JsonSerialization exception and a nullReferenceException" - no, it'll only be throwing one of those. (It might catch one and then throw the other.) Please provide a [mcve], paying attention to formatting to make your code readable. Just having snippets here and there really doesn't help much.

Comment: Well actually I don't have much more than that, I don't even know where the exact line is. I'm continuing someone else's code and I'm lost in this one.

Comment: Well you should at least know which exception is really being thrown, and if you can reproduce it reliably you should be able to create a simpler example.